# Modifying all images from div using css and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

So i have a div with a lot of images:

```
<div id="d1">
    <img id="img1" src="resources/square.png"/>
    <img id="img2" src="resources/square.png"/>
    ...
</div>
```

my css file looks like this:

```
#d1 img {
    width: 5%;
}
```

So, instead of looping over all the images, is it possible to modify the width attribute above using javascript? (I want to modify every image's width)

Comment: yes it is possible eihter by looping with JS or using `querySelectorAll` and `forEach` and adding an attribute to thsoe images.

Comment: If you don't want to loop through all the imgs you could append a style element to your head element which had the required #d1 img setting. This will take precedence over your linked css file

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `querySelectorAll` and combine it with `forEach` to set an attribute to all images within the container.

```js
window.onload = function loop() {
  document.querySelectorAll('#d1 img').forEach(el => el.setAttribute('width', '300'));
}
```

```html
<div id="d1">
    <img id="img1" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100.jpg;"/>
    <img id="img2" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100.jpg;"/>
    <img id="img3" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100.jpg;"/>
    <img id="img4" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100.jpg;"/>
    <img id="img5" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100.jpg;"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Note: the OP asked "instead of looping over all the images".

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, using `querySelectorAll` and a for loop can do the trick and should give you what you want.

```js
const images = document.querySelectorAll('#d1 img');
for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++){

images[i].setAttribute("width", "5%") //Change this to any percent value.

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="d1">
    <img id="img1" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/01/08/13/58/cube-1963036__340.jpg"/>
    <img id="img2" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/01/08/13/58/cube-1963036__340.jpg"/>
    <img id="img3" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/01/08/13/58/cube-1963036__340.jpg"/>

</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

An alternative to using a for loop in querySelectorAll can be to use a `forEach` loop, which will give you the same result.

Comment: this will select all images on the website not only those within that element. Also why use `document.querySelectorAll` when you have that already defined as a variable and could just use the variable? Last but not least you will add a style attribute not set the width as an attribute.

Comment: Oh sorry, guess my mind wasn't working, I created a useless variable by accident, one second I will edit that and set an attribute too.

Comment: Note: the OP asked "instead of looping over all the images".

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to loop. If you use [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) you can set up a variable in your CSS file that `img` initially uses, and then you can use JS to update that variable for all the images.

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--width', '50%');
}, 2000);
```

```css
:root { --width: 5%; }
#d1 img { width: var(--width); }
```

```html
<div id="d1">
  <img id="img1" src="resources/square.png"/>
  <img id="img2" src="resources/square.png"/>
</div>
```